# How to insert a total column in a crosstab report in VS 2008

Tags: designer, report

How to insert a total column in a crosstab (matrix) report in Report Designer in VS 2008?
It seems that i can only insert a subcolumn in a crosstab report.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it now. I just right-clicked the column header and selected Subtotal.